# How to turn off menu bar autohide in split view mode?

Tags: menu-bar, split-view

I use split view quite a bit for programming and want the menu bar to always be shown. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: what is the Mac and OSX

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple () menu, choose System Preferences.

Click Mission Control.

Deselect the option for "Displays have separate Spaces."

Log out and then back in.